# Multiplication of semi-orthogonal and diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ that satisfies $M^{\top}M=D$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. This means that the columns of $M$ are mutually orthogonal to each other. Consider now another diagonal matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Is there anything I can say about the product $B=M^{\top}AM$ ? Under what additional hypotheses, if any, is $B$ also diagonal?

Answer (score 0):

The matrices are related via the Hadamard product $(\odot)$
and the all-ones vector $(\tt1)$
$$\eqalign{
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\op{\operatorname} \def\d{\op{diag}} \def\D{\op{Diag}}
D&=M^TIM &\qiq d = \d(M^TIM) \,&\equiv\, (M\odot M)^T{\tt1} \\
B&=M^TAM &\qiq b = \d(M^TAM) \,&\equiv\, (M\odot M)^Ta \\
}$$
The problem statement asserts that $\,A = \D(a)\;{\rm and}\;D = \D(d),\,$
however it is not necessarily true that $\,B = \D(b)$

The simplest solution that makes $B$ diagonal is to make $M$ a diagonal matrix.